# TextView Overlapping on top And Bottom

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, arduino

So I am creating an android app to communicate with arduino over serial. It is going quite well, but I am having some problems with the layout. My `TextView` is overlapping on both the top and bottom, and I have no idea why!

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jaz8vbx63kd25ix/Screenshot_2012-09-27-18-53-24.png

Here is my main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/demoTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/demoScroller"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/demoText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:typeface="monospace" />

    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sendButton"

        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/send_text"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:singleLine="true" >
     </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely because you're using a [`FrameLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html), which "*should be used to hold a single child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children overlapping each other*". Try using a [`LinearLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) with a vertical orientation.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/demoTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

    <!-- ... -->

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, I had that before, and it does fix the overlap, but now the text box and button move down with the text, instead of staying on the bottom, and when it gets to the bottom it goes off the screen.

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably the `ScrollView`'s height is toying with you. Try setting `android:layout_height="0px"` and `android:layout_weight="1"`. (This will make it take up the remaining space which is not occupied by the `TextView` or `RelativeLayout`.)